# More efficient custom map configuration

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using `AutoMapper` 6.2.2 to convert a view model into a dto model. The view model has 2 matching fields and a single unmatched field which can be converted to 7 other fields. The issue is that the unmatched field is parsed with a static method that produces all 7 alternate fields. So instead of issuing `ForMember` for each of the 7 individual fields and calling a static conversion method each time, how can I map the source `Value` field to 7 destination members in one pass without instantiating it more than once?

```
this.CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FieldA, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => StaticHelper.Parse(src.Value).FieldA))
    // More instances of the same static helper unnecessarily instantiated.
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FieldG, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => StaticHelper.Parse(src.Value).FieldG));
```

Comment: Have you looked into `ConstructUsing` ?

Comment: Brilliant, I am new to AutoMapper and I am just starting to get familiar with it. My problem is solved, write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ConstructUsing` you can build the initial object and map the 7 fields from the one source field via the static method and then let AutoMapper map the remaining fields or continue with `ForMember` to map them manually.